# vertical rhythm using less

Tags: html, css, less

Recently, I've read [this article](http://webtypography.net/2.2.2) about vertical rhythm  and I'm trying to do an implementation based on the article using less and I was wondering if I'm doing it the right way because based on the math it does a 24px font would have a line height of 1px if my math. :D ( I was never too good at math ).

```
.font-size(@target-px-size, @context-px-size: @base-font-size) {
    font-size: @toPx;
    font-size: @toRem;
    .rem(@target-px-size, @context-px-size);
}
.rhythm(@target-px-size) {
    .font-size(@target-px-size);
    @result: unit((@base-line-height / @target-px-size));
    line-height: @result;
    margin-top: unit(@result, px);
    margin-top: unit(@result, rem);
    margin-bottom: unit(@result, px);
    margin-bottom: unit(@result, rem);
}
// Rem Calculator
.rem(@target-px-size, @context-px-size: @base-font-size) {
    @divide-By: unit(@context-px-size);
    @sizeValue: unit(@target-px-size);
    @remValue: round(@sizeValue / @divide-By, 1);
    @toPx: unit(@sizeValue, px);
    @toRem: unit(@remValue, rem);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work.  I have checked it against different values using this site [Vertical rhythm](http://drewish.com/tools/vertical-rhythm/)

**Vertical Rhythm Mixin**

```
.font-size(@target-px-size, @context-px-size: @base-font-size-px) {
    .rem(@target-px-size, @context-px-size);
    font-size: @toPx;
    font-size: @toRem;    
}

.rhythm(@target-px-size) {
    .font-size(@target-px-size);
    @result: unit((@base-line-height-px / @target-px-size));
    line-height: @result;
    margin-top: unit(@result, px);
    margin-top: unit(@result, rem);
    margin-bottom: unit(@result, px);
    margin-bottom: unit(@result, rem);
}

.rem(@target-px-size; @context-px-size: @base-font-size-px){
    @ratio: 1 / @context-px-size;
    @result: unit(@target-px-size * @ratio);
    @toPx: unit(@target-px-size, px);
    @toRem: unit(@result, rem);
}

// Usage
@base-font-size-px: 12px;
@base-line-height-px: 24px;

.bacon {    
    .rhythm(24);
}
```